# ASP.Net Developer wanting to migrate to Ubuntu

Tags: python, php, c#, cms

First time poster, long time admirer...

I develop a lot of ASP.net web pages using Umbraco and DotNetNuke. I've decided that i want to take everything over to Ubuntu and don't mind learning new programming languages (in fact i'm looking forward to it) But i don't want to change what i do in regards to how i approach a new project.

Currently i use a CMS to host my sites and then i build console applications to do back end stuff e.g. My current site uses a C# application to data mine a website where i use that information to remain competitive with my affiliate marketing.

So what would be a good language(s) to learn in order to migrate successfully to Ubuntu with the least amount of downtime.

My understanding is that i would need to learn PHP for the CMS Websites and Python for the terminal programs. But someone has mentioned i can use Python for both.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Sean

Answer (score 1):

If you have web applications developed with ASP.Net the easiest way to migrate to Ubuntu is to simply deploy them with [ModMono](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono). [Mono](http://www.ubuntumanual.org/posts/392/how-to-do-c-and-net-programming-in-ubuntu-using-mono) in general supports most what you do with C# on Windows. Before learning a new language I'd try that route.

Otherwise I'd advise you to go on with Java + Eclipse, thus sticking to high level OO languages.

Comment: Luís de Sousa, "simply deplot them with ModMono." - this was not my experience! Mono packages are good, but I found code needed a lot of changes - Windows specific stuff removing, DB layer altering to using a different database server from MSSQL and various other little glitches.

Comment: If a programmer is trained on high level OO I wouldn't steer him towards script languages. Naturally if you use a specific Windows package you'll have to drop it, no matter the programming language you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a good C# developer you should find using PHP or Python pretty easy to get to grips with (I moved from .net to the Linux-based open source world 8 months ago).

PHP is not a good language, but its popular and with programming experience you should not fall into the many pitfalls of PHP. Use a good framework ASAP, Cake, Sympfony, Yii or Zend for example will help with a more pleasurable PHP development experience.

In the circles I frequent the default CMS seems to be Wordpress and for things too complex for Wordpres, Drupal, but I personally prefer to roll my own with a framework.

For Python you can write for the web, Django is a popular framework.

Also, Ruby on Rail IMHO is worth a good look and is a nice framework/stack for web development.

One big change that you will need to do is to get away from the IDE mentality. Learn how to install and configure from the command line and use a text editor (I like Geany with is like a lightweight IDE), not needing to run a debugger.